# Software to verify digital signatures on executable files

Tags: windows, security

I am looking for a software that can verify digital signatures on executable files (.exe, .dll and similar).

The software

- must run on Windows
- maybe with the help of MinGw, Cygwin or similar
- must validate digital signatures that are contained in the software itself ("certificate directory")
- must validate digital signatures that are contains in digital signature catalogs (since most Microsoft files use that approach)
- must be able to validate multiple signatures on a file
- must support 32 bit and 64 bit executables
- may cost up to 100 €, since I already spent significant amount of time finding a free tool

I have tried:

- `signtool /verify` which comes with the Microsoft SDK
- [SysInternals SigCheck](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441.aspx), which has the ability to validate using catalogs - but it only validates one signature, not all
- asked [a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547311/code-signing-an-executable-twice), but the answer is an incomplete code sample with insufficient error handling - and it's not trivial to make it complete
- [osslsigncode](https://github.com/SummitRoute/osslsigncode-fork), but it does not support catalogs
- [PE Explorer](http://www.heaventools.com/overview.htm) does not support 64 bit executables and is too expensive for my use (230 €, probably because it has many other features that I don't need)